# Select2 width based on the widest option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

Is there a way to make a select2 work like a normal select in terms of width? E.g. the selected element is as wide as the widest element in the list and vice versa. I want to avoid setting a fixed or 100% width. I found a way to get the selected element and the dropdown to adjust automatically each on their own, but not working as a pair. Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish simply with css on the select

```
width: auto
```

Comment: Unfortunately that only seems to adjust to the selected part. In other words, the select will change in width depending on what I select and the dropdown will adjust according to that. I want the selected part and the dropdown to be the same width all the time, based on the widest option.

Comment: Ah ok I understand what your asking